# Workflow on Activity

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-2015

My requirement:

Set the status reason of Incident to X when a new activity(email, task etc) is added to it.

WF shows each activity as its own (email, phonecall etc.) and does not show activity (activity pointers) as a whole.

WF would be ideal, Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Thank you

note: crm 2015 online

Comment: You will need one wf per entity and do it on create of email/phonecall etc and set the status of the regarding record if it's an incident.

Comment: Thanks Rickard, Can this be done via plugin?

Comment: Hi, you have the same issue there since you are creating a new object of type X, that's where the trigger is.